# Debugging a web app on IIS7 without installing IIS6 Metabase

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7

Is it possible to attach (or debug with F5) to IIS7's worker process without installing IIS6 Metabase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigating I found out it's all possible:

- attach to IIS7 worker process or
- debug using F5 functionality

Here's what you have to do:

1. Open web application's properties
2. Select Debug tab
3. Scroll to bottom of the page and set Custom web server address i.e. `http://localhost`
4. Close Visual Studio
5. Start Visual Studio as an administrator (elevated permissions) - I actually changed the taskbar link to VS to always run with elevated permissions, so I don't accidentally forget to right click and select *Run as administrator*

That's it. Debugging of IIS7 web apps **done**.